# C libpcap resolve DLT entries, some nasty bug

Tags: c, libpcap

while sort of writing my own sniffer, I found one example that only starts if it is talking ethernet. Other DLT_types have been ignored. They can be found in pcap-bpf.h I wrote some
lines, that try to implement a missing pcap_resolve_dlt(). It's really nasty code(1), seems to work, though I hit a nasty bug, where one needs to give a space to the corresponding number like:

```
user@debian:~/tmp$ ./resolve_dlt 114
DLT_LTALK       114
user@debian:~/tmp$ ./resolve_dlt 14
DLT_ATM_RFC1483 11
user@debian:~/tmp$ ./resolve_dlt " 14"
DLT_RAW         14
```

Maybe the approach itself is totally wrong and one should grep the pcap-bpf.h directly.

1) http://nopaste.info/4a2470cc83.html, uses strstr()

Kind Regards,

Charles

Tags: C libpcap DLT_

Answer (score 0):

You are doing strstr(dlt[i],argv[1]) so the first "14" matches the text in "DLT_ATM_RFC1483", however the text " 14" matches the text in "DLT_RAW   14".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the token-pasting operator to make this work a little better:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcap-bpf.h>

#define TAB_ENTRY(x) { x, #x }

struct {
    long dlt_code;
    const char *dlt_name;
} dlt_tab[] = {
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_NULL),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_EN10MB),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_EN3MB),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_AX25),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_PRONET),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_CHAOS),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_IEEE802),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_ARCNET),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_SLIP),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_PPP),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_FDDI),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_ATM_RFC1483),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_RAW),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_RAW),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_SLIP_BSDOS),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_PPP_BSDOS),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_SLIP_BSDOS),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_PPP_BSDOS),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_ATM_CLIP),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_REDBACK_SMARTEDGE),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_PPP_SERIAL),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_PPP_ETHER),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_SYMANTEC_FIREWALL),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_C_HDLC),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_C_HDLC),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_IEEE802_11),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_FRELAY),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_LOOP),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_LOOP),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_ENC),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_ENC),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_LINUX_SLL),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_LTALK),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_ECONET),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_IPFILTER),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_PFLOG),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_CISCO_IOS),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_PRISM_HEADER),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_AIRONET_HEADER),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_HHDLC),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_IP_OVER_FC),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_SUNATM),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_RIO),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_PCI_EXP),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_AURORA),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_IEEE802_11_RADIO),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_TZSP),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_ARCNET_LINUX),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_JUNIPER_MLPPP),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_JUNIPER_MLFR),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_JUNIPER_ES),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_JUNIPER_GGSN),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_JUNIPER_MFR),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_JUNIPER_ATM2),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_JUNIPER_SERVICES),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_JUNIPER_ATM1),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_APPLE_IP_OVER_IEEE1394),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_MTP2_WITH_PHDR),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_MTP2),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_MTP3),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_SCCP),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_DOCSIS),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_LINUX_IRDA),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_IBM_SP),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_IBM_SN),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_USER0),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_USER1),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_USER2),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_USER3),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_USER4),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_USER5),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_USER6),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_USER7),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_USER8),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_USER9),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_USER10),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_USER11),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_USER12),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_USER13),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_USER14),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_USER15),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_IEEE802_11_RADIO_AVS),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_JUNIPER_MONITOR),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_BACNET_MS_TP),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_PPP_PPPD),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_PPP_PPPD),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_PPP_PPPD),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_JUNIPER_PPPOE),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_JUNIPER_PPPOE_ATM),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_GPRS_LLC),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_GPF_T),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_GPF_F),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_GCOM_T1E1),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_GCOM_SERIAL),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_JUNIPER_PIC_PEER),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_ERF_ETH),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_ERF_POS),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_LINUX_LAPD),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_JUNIPER_ETHER),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_JUNIPER_PPP),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_JUNIPER_FRELAY),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_JUNIPER_CHDLC),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_MFR),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_JUNIPER_VP),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_A429),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_A653_ICM),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_USB),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_BLUETOOTH_HCI_H4),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_IEEE802_16_MAC_CPS),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_USB_LINUX),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_CAN20B),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_IEEE802_15_4_LINUX),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_PPI),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_IEEE802_16_MAC_CPS_RADIO),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_JUNIPER_ISM),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_IEEE802_15_4),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_SITA),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_ERF),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_RAIF1),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_IPMB),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_JUNIPER_ST),
    TAB_ENTRY(DLT_BLUETOOTH_HCI_H4_WITH_PHDR)
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *endptr = NULL;
    long code;
    int i, found;

    if (argc > 1)
        code = strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 0);

    if (!endptr || endptr == argv[1]) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <dlt_code>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(2);
    }

    found = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < (sizeof dlt_tab / sizeof dlt_tab[0]); i++) {
        if (dlt_tab[i].dlt_code == code) {
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        printf("%ld not found\n", code);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("%ld is %s\n", code, dlt_tab[i].dlt_name);
    return 0;
}
```

Example:

```
$ ./bpf 12
12 is DLT_RAW
$ ./bpf 120
120 is DLT_AIRONET_HEADER
```

(Note that 12 is `DLT_RAW` on Linux systems, not 14).

Comment: Thanks dude, this seems cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

At least with newer versions of libpcap/WinPcap, you can use `pcap_datalink_val_to_name` to map a DLT_ value to the DLT_ name.  `resolve_dlt` could just use strtol() on its first argument and pass the result to `pcap_datalink_val_to_name` (after, of course, checking for errors, and for values that don't fit in an int).